# MySQLdb Python prevent duplicate and optimize muliple inserts

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote this python script to import a specific xls file into mysql. It works fine but if it's run twice on the same data it will create duplicate entries. I'm pretty sure I need to use MySQL `JOIN` but I'm not clear on how to do that. Also is executemany() going to have the same overhead as doing inserts in a loop? I'm obviously trying to avoid that.
**Here's the code in question...**

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    """name is in the 0th col. email is the 4th col."""
    name = sheet.cell(row, 0).value  
    email =  sheet.cell(row, 4).value
    if name and email:
        mailing_list[name.lstrip()] = email.strip()

for n, e in sorted(mailing_list.iteritems()):
    rows.append((n, e))

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, db=dbname, passwd=pwd)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.executemany("""
        INSERT IGNORE INTO mailing_list (name, email) VALUES (%s,%s)""",(rows))
```

### CLARIFICATION...

I read [here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/inserting-multiple-entries-mysql-python) that...

> To be sure, executemany() is effectively the same as simple iteration.
>   However, it is typically faster. It provides an optimized means of
>   affecting INSERT and REPLACE across multiple rows.

Also I took Unodes suggestion and used the UNIQUE constraint. But the `IGNORE` keyword is better than `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because I want it to fail silently.

**TL;DR**

<strike>1. What's the best way prevent duplicate inserts?</strike>
 **ANSWER 1**: UNIQUE contraint on column with `SELECT IGNORE` to fail silently or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to increment the duplicate value and insert it.

1. Is executemany() as expensive as INSERT in a loop?
   @Unode says it's not but my research tells me otherwise. I would like a definitive answer.
2. Is this the best way or is it going to be really slow with bigger
   tables and how would I test to be sure?

Comment: 1) add `unique` constraint on column, where you want to avoid duplicity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 - What's the best way prevent duplicate inserts?**

Depending on what "preventing" means in your case, you have two strategies and one requirement.

The requirement is that you add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column/columns that you want to be unique. This alone will cause an error if insertion of a duplicate entry is attempted. However given you are using `executemany` the outcome may not be what you would expect.

Then as strategies you can do:

- An initial filter step by running a `SELECT` statement before. This means running one SELECT statement per item in your rows to check if it exists already. This strategy works but is inefficient.
- Using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. This automatically triggers an update if the data already exists. For more information refer to [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

**2 - Is executemany() as expensive as INSERT in a loop?**

No, `executemany` creates **one** query which inserts in bulk while doing a for loop will create as many queries as the number of elements in your `rows`.

Comment: I updated my post. I'm not sure if you're correct about executemany()

Comment: @shakabra keep reading that document you linked about `executemany`. It explains that only one query/request is performed to the server but merges all the INSERT statements. Depending on the size of the data you are trying to pass to `executemany` it may happen that the server rejects the request due to `max_allowed_package` size.

Comment: You're right I should have kept reading. I'm taking a look at the source right now. Still don't know if there is a better way though especially in regards to limiting the packet size, although 16mb is alot.

Comment: `executemany` is a trade-off. One big query vs lots of tiny ones. If the big query is too big you can simply break your `rows` into slices. I personally use slices of size 1000 or 10000 depending on the data types.